# how to solve foreign key constraint fails when inserting data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I creating a simple online shopping web site. backend is developed with spring boot and MySQL database.
in that, there are two tables. those are Cart and CartItem.
Cart basically has an Id and it's the primary key of the Cart and also Cart has a List of CartItems.
so every CartItem has an attribute which is cart id and it's the foreign key in the cart item table.

so the problem is when I try to add a new record to the Cart table it's not working and throw errors

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`cartitem`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CART_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`fkcartid`) REFERENCES `cart` (`id`))

This is my table structure

```
create table cart(
    
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    totalprice double,
    itemcount int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CART_ID PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

create table cartitem(
    
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fkcartid int,
    productname text,
    qty int,
    totalprice double,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CARTITEM_ID PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CART_ID FOREIGN KEY (fkcartid) REFERENCES cart(id)
    
    
)
```

this is my models on the project

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private double totalprice;

    private int itemcount;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", referencedColumnName = "id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private List<Cartitem> cartitems;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getTotalprice() {
        return totalprice;
    }

    public void setTotalprice(double totalprice) {
        this.totalprice = totalprice;
    }

    public List<Cartitem> getCartitemtests() {
        return cartitems;
    }

    public void setCartitemtests(List<Cartitem> cartitems) {
        this.cartitems = cartitems;
    }

    public int getItemcount() {
        return itemcount;
    }

    public void setItemcount(int itemcount) {
        this.itemcount = itemcount;
    }

    public List<Cartitem> getCartitems() {
        return cartitems;
    }

    public void setCartitems(List<Cartitem> cartitems) {
        this.cartitems = cartitems;
    }
}

        @Entity
@Table(name = "cartitem")
public class Cartitem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private  int id;

    private int fkcartid;

    private String productname;

    private int qty;

    private double totalprice;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getFkcartid() {
        return fkcartid;
    }

    public void setFkcartid(int fkcartid) {
        this.fkcartid = fkcartid;
    }

    public String getProductname() {
        return productname;
    }

    public void setProductname(String productname) {
        this.productname = productname;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public double getTotalprice() {
        return totalprice;
    }

    public void setTotalprice(double totalprice) {
        this.totalprice = totalprice;
    }
}
```

this is the repository classes

```
@Repository
public interface CartRepo extends CrudRepository<Cart,Integer> {
}

@Repository
public interface CartItemrepo extends CrudRepository<Cartitem,Integer> {
}
```

this is the controller class

```
@RestController
public class homecontroller {

    @Autowired
    basicService basicServiceobj;

   
    @PostMapping(value = "/product")
    public Cart addproduct(@RequestBody Cart cart){
        return basicServiceobj.additems(cart);
    }
}
```

this is the service class

```
@Service
public class basicService {

    @Autowired
    AddressRepo addressRepo;
    @Autowired
    CityRepo cityRepo;

    @Autowired
    CartRepo cartRepo;

    public Cart additems(Cart cart){
        return cartRepo.save(cart);
    }

}
```

this is strack trace

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`cartitem`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CART_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`fkcartid`) REFERENCES `cart` (`id`))
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3199) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3805) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:744) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:712) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:525) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:419) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.test.addressmapping.demo.basicService.additems(basicService.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
at com.test.addressmapping.demo.homecontroller.addproduct(homecontroller.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_261]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_261]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_261]
```

all repositories are extended by the CrudRepository interface spring boot version (2.4.1)
java version (8)

how to solve this problem

Comment: It looks like you try to persist the same cart multiple times. The definitions look okay. Can you [edit] the question to include more code and the stack trace?

Comment: ok i'll do that

Comment: Also, We normally embed objects referenced by foreign keys in JPA entities. So `private int fkcartid` should really be a `@ManyToOne`-annotated `Cart`-field.

Comment: I did edit the question and include all the things that you ask. can you please explain it
with the code.

Comment: Ah I think I see the problem. Through the incorrect setup of the foreign key value `fkcartid` in `Cartitem`, the value of `fkcartid` is most probably `0`, and for the very first persist, no `Cart` with `id 0` exists. This, in turn, leads to the constraint violation on the foreign key constraint. The problem should resolve itself when you uset up the `@ManyToOne`-relation in `Cartitem` as I have suggested in my last comment. Can you please verify that this solves the problem?

Comment: can you please explain to me how to do that. i mean do i need to add another private Cart type variable to CartItem class and use the ManyToOne. I'm new to this. can you please correct that specific part and post it as a comment.

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one over at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that are wrong. I'll try to address it as much as possible. First, for future purposes, it's better to see the sql queries that gets executed by doing the following in the application.properties

```
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Second, as I understand from the way you're building the relationship, it seems that you're building a bi-directional one-to-many mapping. If so, I would recommend adding @ManyToOne in the child entity. Additionally, you would need to add a utility method in order to synchronize this bi-directional mapping. As pointed in the comments the foreign key value will be 0 since you're using primitive type for "id" field. So, the setup becomes the following

Cart Entity

```
public class Cart implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8155938349165825920L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private int totalPrice;
    
    private int itemCount;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;
    
    public void setCart(CartItem cartItem) {
        cartItem.setCart(this);
    }   
  // setters/getters removed for brevity
}
```

CartItem Entity

```
public class CartItem {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String productName;
    
    private int qty;
    
    private double totalPrice;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Cart cart;
  // setters/getters removed for brevity    
}
```

Cart service Impl

```
public interface ICartService {
    
    Cart addCart(Cart cart);
    
}


@Service
public class CartServiceImpl implements ICartService {

    @Autowired
    private CartRepository cartRepository;
    
    @Override
    public Cart addCart(Cart cart) {
        cart.getCartItems().forEach(item -> cart.setCart(item));
        return cartRepository.save(cart);
    }
}
```

Other than this, it's better to use object type for id rather than using primitive type. Why ? because it makes sense to check the persistence of the entity against a "null" value, or else, before persisting the "id" field will have "0" as the value (not null).